# failure to run webdriver test, hudson hang forever

Tags: hudson, webdriver, gradle, geb

My functional test running on hudson every 5 mins. It's working fine except almost(not always) every morning around 6:00 clock(I checked system logs, there is no big jobs eating up system resources at that time), I get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError caused by org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary on port 7055; then the build will hang there forever.

I use gradle to run the geb/webdriver tests, the gradle build seems to start and run until the test step.

I saw this thread http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/3d0bbb40cce5dfac but that seem can not solve my problem.

Any idea how to fix this?  Now I have to get up and stop the failure build
every morning..

### Thanks a lot in advance.

System info: os.name: 'Windows 2003', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.2', java.version: '1.5.0_18' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: Wasn't hudson replaced by Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

The url to thread you refer to seems to be faulty.

I have been having troubles with gradle hanging now and again. Those cases seem to have been due to an unreleased lock in the .gradle directory in the user home directory. Removing the .gradle directory fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks. The server running this hudson jobs is headvy loaded and CPU frequently reach 100% during the job running, and I think that has something to do with the error?